# Javascript var as argument in c# mvc3 razor

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm developing a web in MVC3 razor and I want to send as an argument a javascript variable, but I don't know if this is posible. The code is something like this:

```
function clean(caja) {
    @{
        Inicio.Controllers.kitClass kit = new Inicio.Controllers.kitClass(caja);
        kit.clean();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've updated my example to show you can do this using an Encapsulated method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not. you will have to make an ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a razor var to a function you can do this:

```
@{
    var someItem = "Hello! Welcome to MVC";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert(@someItem );
    });
</script>
```

I think you might consider something like this as an alternative:

@{

```
var kit = new Test.Controllers.kitClass("something");
Func<bool,bool> Incio = delegate(bool cleanMe) { return kit.clean(); };
```

}

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        executeTheFunc();
    });
    function executeTheFunc() {
       if('@Incio(true)' == 'True'){
            alert("This is clean!");
       } else {
            alert("This is not clean!");
       }
    }
</script>
```

***Mock class - not sure what yours looks like:***

```
public class kitClass {
    public kitClass(string something) {

    }
    public bool clean() { return true; }
}
```

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx

Comment: This is the other way round. He wants to send a javascript variable to  a .NET instance method.